# Wordpress alternate css file to working

Tags: css, wordpress, alternate

Hi everyone for  the help in advance: Im trying to get a 2nd header added to a custom temp page and in that alternate header all an alternate css file different from style.css.

I called the custom header from the cat template  page like this

```
<?php get_header('header_state'); ?>
```

It works fine and places the header on the page and I called the css file in this custom header like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>//localhost:8888/cnb_press/wp-content/themes/cnb-zip1/state_style.css" media="screen" />
```

but my page is still accessing the index.php style.css for some reason. I am on a MAMP and not live.

Any ideas why I am not getting this right?

Comment: See the link might be help full for you se template_directory, template_url http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_bloginfo

Answer (score 0):

If your page is still showing the incorrect CSS link tag, you aren't loading the new header template you created. WordPress wouldn't redirect an absolutely URLed CSS file referenced in the header.

Look at the WordPress template hierarchy to make sure your page is loading the template you think it is:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks that does seem to be the problem.  I read through the link you provided but still don't know what is not working.  I have a static html page I am just trying to test the theme of and am not sure why it won't work?